# Camera stream not loading on all devices with maximum quality requirements (HTML/Angular)

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, camera

I'm developing an application in Angular to capture a photo with the maximum possible quality depending on the device's camera.

Currently, I have this code:

HTML:

`<video #video id="video" autoplay muted playsinline></video>`

Angular TS:

```
_requestCameraStream(width: number, height: number, secondTry: boolean) {
    if (navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia)
    {
      navigator.mediaDevices
        .getUserMedia({
          video: {
            facingMode: 'environment',
            width: { ideal: width },
            height: { ideal: height },
            frameRate: { ideal: 30 },
          },
        })
        .then(stream => {
          console.log('_getUserMedia -> stream loaded');
          this.loadStream(stream);
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err);

          if (!secondTry)
          {
            console.log('Started second try');
            this._requestCameraStream(2560, 1440, true);
          }
          else
          {
            this.router.navigateByUrl('id-document/camera-error');
          }
        });
    }
  }

  private loadStream(stream: MediaStream) {
    const videoDevices = stream.getVideoTracks();
            
    this.lastStream = stream;
    this.video!.nativeElement.srcObject = stream;
    this.video!.nativeElement.play();
    this.ref.detectChanges();
  }
```

Basically I check if the device has a camera available and try to load it with the width and height values that the function receives. On the first try I call the function as follows:

```
this._requestCameraStream(4096, 2160, false);
```

If the stream fails to load (probably because the camera does not support 4k quality) then it tries again with the values `this._requestCameraStream(2560, 1440, true);`

This is actually working pretty well on most devices, but on a Galaxy Note 10 Plus, the stream does not load, but if I click the button to take the picture, the camera does capture the image in 4k quality.

I suspect that the camera has a higher resolution than the screen, so the camera can capture a 4k image, but the screen can't load a 4k video as a preview. The problem is: the system does not trigger any warning or errors that I could capture. It is as if the preview loaded successfully.

How can I detect and treat this error? Or maybe, is there any other way that I can request the camera to capture a maximum quality image with the preview loading correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You can try defining a range of resolutions instead of trying only two

```
async _requestCameraStream() {
    if (!navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) return;
    try {
        const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices
            .getUserMedia({
                              video: {
                                  facingMode: {
                                     exact: "environment"
                                  },
                                  width: { min: 2288, ideal: 4096, max: 4096 },
                                  height: { min: 1080, ideal: 2160, max: 2160 },
                                  frameRate: { ideal: 30 },
                              },
                          });
        if(stream) {
            console.log('_getUserMedia -> stream loaded');
            this.loadStream(stream);
        }
    }catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        this.router.navigateByUrl('id-document/camera-error');
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried using min and max, but it doesn't work. In the experiences I made the device always use the ideal value, even if it throws an error. That's why I added the "retry" logic.

Comment: @LeonardoDias try to add 'exact' to "facingMode". if its not working i sugget that you should try to use `const devices = await navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices();` and set the device id under the 'video' property: `video: { devideId: .... }`

Answer (score 0):

I think your current approach is correct to capture the maximum quality image. I have used a similar approach in one of my projects. I think the problem is with the video playback. There is an autoplay policy in the browser it behaves differently in a different browser. This browser policy does not allow to play video content without any user intervention. Check this URL, https://developer.chrome.com/blog/autoplay/

I think you should add a muted attribute in the video element and would be better if you ask the user to click before capturing the camera stream. May be this does not solve the problem which you are facing but this problem will be there in some browsers like iPhone. Apple devices do not allow any video content without user intervention.

Regards,
omi

Comment: The HTML tag already has a "muted" modifier as you can see in the code, so the video can autoplay in all devices, including iPhone. I tested in multiple browsers and multiple devices. It works perfectly, so that is not the issue here.. It just doesn't work on specific devices, like the Note 10. Also, even after the user clicks or interacts with the page, the preview still doesn't load and no error or warning is triggered

Answer (score 0):

```
     <div class="row justify-content-center">


        <video class="col-11 col-lg-8 sbordure" [class.show]="!isCaptured" [class.hide]="isCaptured" #video
          id="video" [width]="640" autoplay></video>

        <canvas class="col-11 col-lg-8 sbordure" [class.show]="isCaptured" [class.hide]="!isCaptured" #canvas
          id="canvas" [width]="WIDTH" [height]="HEIGHT"></canvas>
      </div>

      <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <button class="col-8 col-md-4 mt-3 photo-bouton" mat-raised-button 
          *ngIf="!isCaptured" color="primary" (click)="capture()">Prendre une photo</button>
        <button class="col-8 col-md-4 mt-3 photo-bouton" mat-raised-button *ngIf="isCaptured" color="primary"
          (click)="removeCurrent()">Prendre une autre photo</button>

      </div>
```